# Google Maps API not popping up

Tags: google-maps

So I have a website: terpconnect.umd.edu/~ybencheq and I basically wanted to feature a Google Maps at the bottom of my page. I generated an API key and I have it passed in the key parameter. The URL's in my credentials are: https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~ybencheq/*, https://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~ybencheq/*, *.terpconnect.umd.edu/* and none of these will work. I get the RefererNotAllowedMapError and sometimes I don't even get an error in my console; it just turns up blank on that part of the page).

Here's what I have:

```
<!-- Add Google Maps -->
<script>

function myMap()
{
  myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(38.9869, 76.9426);
  var mapOptions= {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: false,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myCenter,
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
```

And:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[insertkeyhere]" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You never call the `myMap` function.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself** (not a link to an external site).

Comment: Woops! I added my code :)

Comment: As I said, you are never calling the `myMap` function that I can see.  Where do you think that is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `myMap` function somewhere.  Either call it onload:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',myMap);
```

Or in the call back of the API load:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap&key=[insertkeyhere]" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(but not both)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nvjt3a2w/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function myMap() {
  myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9869, 76.9426);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 12,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", myMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```